# Set API Gateway integration request timeout with Serverless Framework

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

Is it possible to set a custom request integration timeout in AWS API Gateway in `serverless.yml` configuration?

Although the question is quite straight forward I find a little of context always useful:

I need to notify the final user when the lambda function has timed out. Such situation could happen due to project requirements (lambda is communicating with third-party systems that may not be up). I came up with some other solutions, I believe setting the API-GW request timeout to the same time as lambda timeout is the best one, though.

Comment: Do you ask, how to set specific timeout for APIGW endpoint?

Or do you ask how to notify user that you're unable to fulfill request, before actually timeout takes place?

Comment: @MariuszNowak I ask how to set a specific timeout for APIGW endpoint :)

Comment: Unfortunately there's no out of a box supported for that in Serverless Framework.

Still please post a request, also PR is very welcome

Comment: @MariuszNowak Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: For now using AWS CLI is the best bet to manually update the integration timeout. This is what we used to solve our issue manually.

`aws  apigatewayv2 update-integration --integration-id <integration-id> --api-id <api id> --timeout-in-millis <time in milliseconds> `

Answer (score 3):

Realised that with the [recent update in serverless framework](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/7420/commits/306710a03413304198ad4f9e4c6908b1bfdd2ae8) - function timeout is respected across the integration. All you have to do is pass timeout value in your function.

Here is an example:

`functions:
    myfunction:
        handler: public/index.php
        timeout: 15 #This will be same for integration timeout in API Gateway.
        tags:
          project: myproject`

Comment: Note that this only applies if you use the HTTP API integration. It doesn't apply for the REST API integration.